# Xtext Code Generation: Get raw String from XBlockExpression

Tags: code-generation, xtext, emf, xtend, xbase

Currently I am working on code generation based on an Xtext-DSL. Now I am facing the following problem:

I'm generating an .xtend file with my own implementation of the IGenerator interface. Everything works flawless but I can't access the raw String from an XBlockExpression in my DSL. I can only access the EMF-AST with all the attributes but re-generating the raw code from the model seems like a lot of overhead since I really just need all the code from withtin the XBlockExpression.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always access the textual representation via the so called node model. the class `NodeModelUtils`gives you access to it e.g. by calling `findActualNodeFor`. The resulting `INode` can be asked for its text

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.